# Is it possible to point a domain name to my home directory on university's server (no root access)

Tags: dns-hosting

I have a webpage in my home directory in my university's RHEL 5.11 server that is accessible via www.univerisity.edu/~uname.

I have a domain name registered with godaddy and I would like to point that domain to my university web page.

Is this possible given I only have write privileges in my home directory of the university server?

If so, How can it be done?

Comment: You can do it with GoDaddy's URL forwarding, which is a redirect and won't keep your domain name. Or with masking which uses an IFRAME and won't completely hide your real domain. To do it well, you'd need a server with a reverse-proxy (but then you wouldn't need your university site at all) or you'd need to add config on the university server to accept your domain name.

Comment: It is easy, if the university allows it. Contact your system administrator.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably not.

You'd have to point an a record at your university's public IP address and have that forwarded to the web server. I very much doubt they will want to forward all requests on port 80 to your webspace.

What you could do, however, is redirect your GoDaddy registered URL to www.univerisity.edu/~uname